# How to pass variable value into script tag in ejs file?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parameter-passing, ejs

I am trying to implement Collapsable Tree in d3.

I have a code like the following in my .ejs file.

```
<div class="space5px" >
    <%= startNode %>
    <%= console.log(treeData) %>
</div>

<div id="tree-container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var treeData = treeData;
...
```

I can see the name value on the console but `treeData` becomes undefined in script part (at `var treeData = treeData`).
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by using `JSON.stringify(treeData)` and then `JSON.parse('<%- treeData %>')`. Do not waste your time!